# Problem with suspending and resuming job

Tags: bash

I have a driver script which manages a job string which can run jobs in parallel or sequentially based on a dependency graph. For example:

```
Job              Predecessors

A                null
B                A
C                A
D                B
E                D, C
F                E
```

The driver starts A in the background and waits for it to complete by suspending itselfusing bash built-in `suspend`. On completion, job A sends a `SIGCONT` to the driver which would then start B and C in the background and suspend itself again, and so on.

The driver has a `set -m` so job control is enabled.

This works fine when the driver is itself started in background. However, when the driver is invoked in the foreground, the **first call** to suspend works **fine**. The **second call** seems to turn into an '`exit`' which reports a "`There are stopped jobs`" and **does not exit**. The **third call** to suspend also turns into an '`exit`' and **kills the driver and all children** [as it should considering this is the second converted call to '`exit`'].

And this is my question: **Is this expected behavior?** If so, why and **how do I work around it?**

Thanks.

Code fragments below:

Driver:

```
            for step in $(hash_keys 'RUNNING_HASH')
            do
                    proc=$(hash_find 'RUNNING_HASH' $step)
                    if [ $proc ]
                    then
                            # added the grep to ensure the process is found
                            ps -p $proc | grep $proc > /dev/null 2>&1
                            if [ $? -eq 0 ]
                            then
                                    log_msg_to_stderr $SEV_DEBUG "proc $proc running: suspending execution"
                                    suspend 
                                    # execution resumes here on receipt of SIGCONT
                                    log_msg_to_stderr $SEV_DEBUG "signal received: continuing execution"
                                    break
                            fi
                    fi
            done
```

Job:

```
## $$ is the driver's PID
kill -SIGCONT $$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to think you are over-complicating things playing with job control and suspend, etc.  Here is an example program which keeps 5 children running at all times.  Once a second it looks to see if anyone went away (much more efficiently than ps|grep, BTW) and starts up a new child if necessary.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

set -o monitor
trap "pkill -P $$ -f 'sleep 10\.9' >&/dev/null" SIGCHLD

totaljobs=15
numjobs=5
worktime=10
curjobs=0
declare -A pidlist

dojob()
{
  slot=$1
  time=$(echo "$RANDOM * 10 / 32768" | bc -l)
  echo Starting job $slot with args $time
  sleep $time &
  pidlist[$slot]=`jobs -p %%`
  curjobs=$(($curjobs + 1))
  totaljobs=$(($totaljobs - 1))
}

# start
while [ $curjobs -lt $numjobs -a $totaljobs -gt 0 ]
 do
  dojob $curjobs
 done

# Poll for jobs to die, restarting while we have them
while [ $totaljobs -gt 0 ]
 do
  for ((i=0;$i < $curjobs;i++))
   do
    if ! kill -0 ${pidlist[$i]} >&/dev/null
     then
      dojob $i
      break
     fi
   done
   sleep 10.9 >&/dev/null
 done
wait
```

Comment: @SethRobinson: Thanks for the tip on using kill -0 to look for job existence. I am using the driver script to control a 480 month simulation where each month's simulation consists of 8-10 jobs and takes about 20 seconds. Every 1 second of sleep adds 5% to my run time which I cannot afford. I actually have a sleep-based polling script to manage other jobs which are not time critical.

Comment: sleep .1 then?  In any case I modified my example program to trap SIGCHLD and interrupt the sleep (using a magic sleep time to avoid killing the wrong sleep).  I also changed to non-integral job lengths to demonstrate that it actually provides sub-second response.

Comment: @SethRobinson: This is a good workaround. I had tried to trap SIGCHLD before going for the suspend and SIGCONT approach but was having some trouble. Will try to use it again with your example. Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: `set -o monitor` is required to allow a non-interactive shell script to use SIGCHLD.

Answer (score 0):

Do the worker jobs exit when they're finished? If so, rather than using `suspend` and SIGCONT, how about simply using `wait $PIDS` in the driver script?

Comment: Worker jobs do exit when they are finished. The problem with wait $PIDS is that it does not return until all worker jobs end. I want to examine my dependency graph each time a job ends so I can start new jobs if possible.

Comment: I suppose you know this, but you can wait for any sized list of PIDs.   Interesting question, but don't have time today to dig in on it. Good luck!

Comment: @shelter: You can, but wait will wait for *all* of them to finish. Our asker here would want to wait for *any* of them to finish, hence the use of suspend/SIGCONT. It is an interesting question. I hope to come up with another answer!